# Can I create the following column Family in cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, command-line-interface, bigdata

I need to make small POC in Cassandra and I need to create column Family of the following type:

User with unique string id (for example '1234')should store all his incomming messages ordered by time stamp.

```
   "1234"=> 
    [
      1348008041376000 : {  target_uid : 4321, msg : "Hello, how are you?" },
      1348008041377000 : {  target_uid : 3213, msg : "And how Are you?" }
    ] ,
    "4321"=> 
    [
      1348008041376000 : {  target_uid : 1234, msg : "Thank you I'm fine." },
      1348008041377000 : {  target_uid : 2345, msg : "And how Are you?" }
    ]
```

I googled for a long time and have seen alot of examples, but I still can't realize what type of COLUMN FAMILY should it be?

I totally new in Cassandra and I know that it sounds like homework :), but please help.

**Update:**

I'm trying to create the following cli Create Family column, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 CREATE COLUMN FAMILY messages with comparator = DateType and key_validation_class=UTF8Type AND column_metadata=[ {column_name: msg, validation_class: UTF8Type}];
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: unable to coerce 'msg' to a  formatted date (long)
```

Can you please help with cli syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for versions prior to 1.1.  It assumes you're storing your JSON values in a wide row (you manage your own serialization).

```
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY Example 
  ( user_id text PRIMARY KEY ) 
  WITH comparator=timestamp;
```

For version 1.1 onward, have a look at this document for further guidance:  http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1

Comment: thank you for response, I'm just trying to do it in cli and I created query which according to my understanding will do the same as your query, but something is wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: You've defined a comparator (column name) to be of type DateType, and then are redefining a text-based column name "msg" in the column metadata.  The first technique is appropriate for a dynamic column family, and the second for a static column family.  You need to do one or the other.

Comment: Use `default_validation_class` rather than `column_metadata`.